# Access VBA LIKE operator

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have created a form that queries a database by multiple fields, however the fields are optional so I use `LIKE`.
I have ran a query to return all orders that have been placed on 8/11/2019 and that are in `AnalysisCode2 = 'Spray Area'`.

When ran on my own form I get returned 3 orders, however when I filter down the database manually I get 7 orders.

[image: Orders returned when ran through my own form.]

I went through the table below and removed filters, to find that `AnalysisCode1` and `AnalysisCode3` had filters and once I removed these all 7 orders appear.

[image: Orders returned when I filter the database manually]

[image: removing filters on analysis code 1 and 3 which my form puts on]

This is where I'm confused as I don't know why there is filters on these two fields as I have use the `LIKE` operator and these columns are blank in the missing records.

This is my query in the back end:

```vb
Public Sub Command121_Click()

 Dim task As String

task = "select * from SageOrderLines_Live where [PromisedDeliveryDate] = " & Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " AND [CustomerAccountNumber] LIKE '" & Me.CustomerAccount & "*' AND [Code] LIKE '" & Me.Product & "*' AND [AnalysisCode1] LIKE '" & Me.Analysis1 & "*' AND [AnalysisCode2] LIKE '" & Me.Analysis2 & "*' AND [AnalysisCode3] LIKE '" & Me.Analysis3 & "*'"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task


End Sub
```

Comment: hi, maybe they aren't blank but empty. i think that like doenst like empty fields.. try to  change `Me.Analysis1` to `Me.Analysis1 & ""` `Me.Analysis3` to `Me.Analysis3 & ""` to see if makes diference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null field will not meet the wildcard criteria. An empty string will. If you want to return records where value is Null then need to handle by converting to empty string.

`AND [AnalysisCode1] & '' LIKE '" & Me.Analysis1 & "*'`

Could conditionally build WHERE clause so only controls with inputs are considered. Review [how to show query results in a datasheet in the same form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827047/how-to-show-query-results-in-a-datasheet-in-the-same-form/5844215#5844215). However, Null fields will still have to be handled to provide an alternate value if you want those records retrieved when there is an input to corresponding control.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a stored query and not a VBA string query that directly references your form values with `NZ` to account for empty fields. This helps avoid the need to `FORMAT` dates or use `LIKE`. Then base your datasheet RecordSource to saved query and have buttonClick event trigger [`Requery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.requery) of datasheet.

**SQL** *(assign below to recordsource of datasheet)*

Below handles optional form controls but returns only non-NULL records:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SageOrderLines_Live 
WHERE [PromisedDeliveryDate] = NZ(Form!myForm!DateFrom, [PromisedDeliveryDate])
  AND [CustomerAccountNumber] = NZ(Form!myForm!CustomerAccount, [CustomerAccountNumber])
  AND [Code] = NZ(Form!myForm!Product, [Code])
  AND [AnalysisCode1] = NZ(Form!myForm!Analysis1, [AnalysisCode1])
  AND [AnalysisCode2] = NZ(Form!myForm!Analysis2, [AnalysisCode2])
  AND [AnalysisCode3] = NZ(Form!myForm!Analysis3, [AnalysisCode3])
```

Should you need to capture missing values, run `NZ` on both sides of `AND` equality expressions with ***same*** default value. While dense, below only has to be run one time and never seen again!

```sql
SELECT * FROM SageOrderLines_Live 
WHERE NZ([PromisedDeliveryDate], 'default') = NZ(NZ(Form!myForm!DateFrom, [PromisedDeliveryDate]), 'default')
  AND NZ([CustomerAccountNumber], 'default') = NZ(NZ(Form!myForm!CustomerAccount, [CustomerAccountNumber]), 'default')
  AND NZ([Code], 'default') = NZ(NZ(Form!myForm!Product, [Code]), 'default')
  AND NZ([AnalysisCode1], 'default') = NZ(NZ(Form!myForm!Analysis1, [AnalysisCode1]), 'default')
  AND NZ([AnalysisCode2], 'default') = NZ(NZ(Form!myForm!Analysis2, [AnalysisCode2]), 'default')
  AND NZ([AnalysisCode3], 'default') = NZ(NZ(Form!myForm!Analysis3, [AnalysisCode3]), 'default')
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub Command121_Click()
    Me.myDataSheetForm.Requery
End Sub
```