# How to display the results of a search Query (done by clicking a "Search" Button) in a Subform?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, subform

I'm working on a DB in Microsoft Access 2016 and created a search form with multiple filters and then a Search button. It works perfectly fine, it shows the results in a query table that opens separately but I would like the results to be shown on the form page right below the button.

I tried:

- creating a list box and setting the row source to my query
- dragging the query itself on my form page to create a subquery and it only every data in the DB. The query is still functional, it opens in another tab and works, but the subform doesn't change at all
- creating a combo box and displaying the results after pressing the button in the said combo box
- adding another button in the subform to run the query but it has the same outcome: results displayed in a separate tab.

[pic of what I want my form to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apZga.jpg)

I attached a pic, that's not my actual DB. Basically I want the box to display my results only after clicking the button.

Nothing has worked :( is there anything else I could try? I would gladly post my .accdb file if it's easier to understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try F9 on the list box, or Shift+F9 on the subform query? If that changes anything, you simply need to `.Requery` them when searching.

Comment: Apply criteria to form Filter property. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827047/how-to-show-query-results-in-a-datasheet-in-the-same-form

Comment: @June7 I literally have no idea where the lines of code belong so that's kind of hard to follow

Comment: @Andre nothing happened :(

Comment: Did you download and explore Allen Browne sample?

Comment: @June7 yes I did, sadly I don't understand much about the code. I'm very new to programming especially in access aka I just started last week. I also don't understand how his form even works if he doesn't have a table with all the data. I'll just keep exploring a bit I guess, hopefully I figure it out! :)

Comment: There are actually 2 tables. Just has navigation pane showing only the form and not other object groups. Suggest you spend a solid week studying an introductory tutorial book.

Comment: I would gladly do that but this part of the project is due on Monday. It’s actually a school project but we aren’t getting any help from our teachers since they “haven’t worked with access in years” and “would prefer if we used something like php”. So we’re pretty much on our own! Thanks for the tips though, I’ll definitely keep searching.