# Access Show Multiple Records for One Name

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a form that allows the user to choose a students name. When the name is selected the form updates to show that particular student's description of the test and the mark they received. Students can take multiple tests. However, the output on the form only shows one test description and one mark even if multiple have been taken. How can I get the form to display multiple descriptions and marks if needed? Below is an example of "Alan" who has taken 2 tests but only one test is output.
[image]

Comment: Use `Subform` or continuous form to display multiple records.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have changed the form into a continuous form. However, now it is showing all of the records present instead of the tests for the particular student. Do you know how I would go about fixing this?

Comment: How does your form 'update' with selection in combobox? Shows all what records - all students? Is the combobox bound? A control used for input/selection of filter criteria should be UNBOUND. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show query results in a datasheet in the same form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827047/how-to-show-query-results-in-a-datasheet-in-the-same-form)

Comment: Thank you for the read. All student test descriptions, and marks are being shown regardless of what choice is selected in the combobox. I have made the combobox unbound but am still running into the same issue. For example, if I choose the student "Alan" in the combobox instead of only Alan's test description and marks showing it is also showing the test description and marks for all other students in the table.

Comment: Have to apply filter to form or use a dynamic parameterized query as form RecordSource. Both described in referenced links. Until you have code with specific issue for us to analyze, little else can offer for advice.