# Searching for data in a combo list

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with a table ALL_INCOME which contains all my data with reference to income.

I managed to create a search button which is able to search the data in a date range successfully.

My table has these fields:

Date,Type of income, Amount.

I will like to search in a date range so it can pick a specific type of income records to be displayed.

For instance, if I have investment, savings as the type of income in my table and also in my combo list, I will like to be able to search in a date range using a specific type of income.

These are my codes which is able to search data in a date range that displays all data.

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()
' Search button
Call Search
End Sub

Sub Search()
Dim strCriteria, task As String

Me.Refresh
If IsNull(Me.OrderDateFrom) Or IsNull(Me.OrderDateTo) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the date range", vbInformation, "Date Range Required"
    Me.OrderDateFrom.SetFocus

Else
    strCriteria = "([DATE] >= #" & Me.OrderDateFrom & "# And [DATE] <= #" & Me.OrderDateTo & "#)"
    task = "select * from ALL_INCOME where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [DATE]"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
    
End If
End Sub
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is issue? Error message, wrong result, nothing happens? If you want to include criteria for type of income then do so. Include a combobox for selection of income type and include that in the VBA to construct criteria.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show query results in a datasheet in the same form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827047/how-to-show-query-results-in-a-datasheet-in-the-same-form)

Comment: The issue is, I can add the combo to the form but how to include it in the vba code to construct a criteria is the problem.

Comment: Can you please use my code posted here to make a new vba code which will meet that criteria for me?

Comment: No. You can follow the link I provided and read it. It will lead to a tutorial that can guide you. Make attempt and when you have specific issue with new code, post question.

Comment: Is like you don’t get me. Am a novice when it comes to vba. Have gone through your post and am not seeing how I can apply it to mine for it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  below codes. It will search specific `IncomeType` between two date range. If you do not select any `IncomeType` then it will filter all `IncomeType` in specified date range.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdApplyFilter_Click()
    Call Search
End Sub

Sub Search()
Dim strCriteria, task As String

Me.Refresh
If IsNull(Me.OrderDateFrom) Or IsNull(Me.OrderDateTo) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the date range", vbInformation, "Date Range Required"
    Me.OrderDateFrom.SetFocus

Else
    strCriteria = "[MyDate] >= " & Format(Me.OrderDateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
                  " And [MyDate] <= " & Format(Me.OrderDateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
                  " AND [IncomeType] LIKE '" & IIf(IsNull(Me.cboIncomeType), "*", Me.cboIncomeType) & "'"
    'task = "select * from ALL_INCOME where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [DATE]"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strCriteria
    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Adjust `[MyDate]` and `[IncomeType]` with your table field name. Also adjust `cboIncomeType` with your combobox name.

Comment: Well noted. Will give it a try and get back to you Sir